# How to put CSS and HTML in one page of code?

Tags: html, css

these are what i have, and would like to know how to put them both together in one page of code. 
This as you can tell is copied from a website, but let me assure you, its copyright free material. I know that this question might been seen as a duplicate, but as far as i have looked, i have not seen an answer on how it is done-e.g, how do you combine both, all i have seen is the code all in one. (P.S I am a N00B, and first question, so forgive me if i make mistakes)
Many thanks

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.about {
  margin: 70px auto 40px;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 260px;
  font: 10px/18px 'Lucida Grande', Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #bbb;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background: #383838;
  background: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.8);
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.about a {
  color: #eee;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.1s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.1s;
  -o-transition: background 0.1s;
  transition: background 0.1s;
}
.about a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #555;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
}

.about-links {
  height: 30px;
}
.about-links > a {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.about-author {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.about-author > a {
  padding: 1px 3px;
  margin: 0 -1px;
}

/*
 * Copyright (c) 2012-2013 Thibaut Courouble
 * http://www.cssflow.com
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT License:
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 */
body {
  font: 13px/20px 'Lucida Grande', Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: #404040;
  background: #e6e6e6 url("../img/bg.png") 0 0 repeat;
}

.container {
  margin: 100px auto;
  width: 720px;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav {
  height: 48px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.nav > li, .nav:active > .active {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 0 4px;
  height: 44px;
  color: #595959;
  text-shadow: 0 1px white;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #cfcfcf #d6d6d6 #c8c8c8;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25));
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25));
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px white, inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), 0 2px #dadada, 0 3px #c4c4c4, 0 4px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px white, inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), 0 2px #dadada, 0 3px #c4c4c4, 0 4px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.nav > li:hover {
  color: #539f07;
  text-shadow: 0 1px white, 0 0 20px white;
}
.nav > li.active,
.nav > .active:active,
.nav > li:active {
  z-index: 2;
  margin: 4px 0 0;
  height: 43px;
  color: #404040;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: #ccc;
  border-width: 1px 0;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35), inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35), inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}
.nav > li:active {
  z-index: 3;
}
.nav > li:first-child {
  border-left-width: 1px !important;
  border-left-color: #c6c6c6;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
.nav > li:last-child {
  border-right-width: 1px !important;
  border-right-color: #c6c6c6;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
.nav > li + li, .nav:active > .active + li, .nav:active > li + .active {
  border-left-width: 0;
}
.nav > .active + li,
.nav > .active:active + li,
.nav > li:active + li,
.nav > li:active + .active {
  border-left-width: 1px;
}
.nav > li > a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 44px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: 0;
}
.nav > li > a:before {
  content: attr(title);
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 20px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  text-shadow: none;
}
.nav .nav-icon {
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.nav .nav-icon:before {
  display: none;
}

[class*="icon-"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  background-image: url("../img/icons.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: transparent;
  font: 0/0 serif;
  text-shadow: none;
  color: transparent;
}

.icon-home {
  background-position: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]--><head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title>Light Horizontal Navigation</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
  <section class="container">
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="index.html" class="nav-icon" title="Home"><span class="icon-home">Home</span></a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html" title="Volenteering">Volenteering</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html" title="Donate">Donate</a></li>
      </ul>
            </ul>
   </nav>
  </section>
   
    </p>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style might be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you would do it, although I don't recommend it. It's far easier to maintain your code by including a style sheet and keeping your markup/CSS separate.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]--><head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title>Light Horizontal Navigation</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
</head>
<style>
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.about {
  margin: 70px auto 40px;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 260px;
  font: 10px/18px 'Lucida Grande', Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #bbb;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background: #383838;
  background: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.8);
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.about a {
  color: #eee;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.1s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.1s;
  -o-transition: background 0.1s;
  transition: background 0.1s;
}
.about a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #555;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
}

.about-links {
  height: 30px;
}
.about-links > a {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.about-author {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.about-author > a {
  padding: 1px 3px;
  margin: 0 -1px;
}

/*
 * Copyright (c) 2012-2013 Thibaut Courouble
 * http://www.cssflow.com
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT License:
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 */
body {
  font: 13px/20px 'Lucida Grande', Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: #404040;
  background: #e6e6e6 url("../img/bg.png") 0 0 repeat;
}

.container {
  margin: 100px auto;
  width: 720px;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav {
  height: 48px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.nav > li, .nav:active > .active {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 0 4px;
  height: 44px;
  color: #595959;
  text-shadow: 0 1px white;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #cfcfcf #d6d6d6 #c8c8c8;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25));
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25));
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px white, inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), 0 2px #dadada, 0 3px #c4c4c4, 0 4px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px white, inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), 0 2px #dadada, 0 3px #c4c4c4, 0 4px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.nav > li:hover {
  color: #539f07;
  text-shadow: 0 1px white, 0 0 20px white;
}
.nav > li.active,
.nav > .active:active,
.nav > li:active {
  z-index: 2;
  margin: 4px 0 0;
  height: 43px;
  color: #404040;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: #ccc;
  border-width: 1px 0;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35), inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35), inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}
.nav > li:active {
  z-index: 3;
}
.nav > li:first-child {
  border-left-width: 1px !important;
  border-left-color: #c6c6c6;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
.nav > li:last-child {
  border-right-width: 1px !important;
  border-right-color: #c6c6c6;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
.nav > li + li, .nav:active > .active + li, .nav:active > li + .active {
  border-left-width: 0;
}
.nav > .active + li,
.nav > .active:active + li,
.nav > li:active + li,
.nav > li:active + .active {
  border-left-width: 1px;
}
.nav > li > a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 44px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: 0;
}
.nav > li > a:before {
  content: attr(title);
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 20px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  text-shadow: none;
}
.nav .nav-icon {
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.nav .nav-icon:before {
  display: none;
}

[class*="icon-"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  background-image: url("../img/icons.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: transparent;
  font: 0/0 serif;
  text-shadow: none;
  color: transparent;
}

.icon-home {
  background-position: 0 0;
}
</style>
<body>
  <section class="container">
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="index.html" class="nav-icon" title="Home"><span class="icon-home">Home</span></a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html" title="Volenteering">Volenteering</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html" title="Donate">Donate</a></li>
      </ul>
            </ul>
   </nav>
  </section>
   
    </p>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, may i ask exactly how one would do this, in case i am with this problem in the foreseeable future?

Comment: You take whatever css you have and wrap it in `<style></style>` tags

Comment: You are a legend, thanks a lot, this is going to be a pain trying to sort out i think, now i have to add all this to the website i am building, and make sure that all links work, and so that the allocated button is highlight for the page i am on. I also cant english.

Comment: It's better to put the CSS in separate file so it can be cached. Your critical rendering CSS can be placed inline and the rest should be dynamically loaded

Comment: @AbbasA You're welcome. And don't worry about it, I'm American, we don't English well either...